# SBT - Unable to save file on Windows 7

Tags: sbt

I'm running a lift web app using sbt. After I run the following command - `container:start` and modify any css files and save them I get the message that `"The file is opened in another program"`. I checked the process and SBT is keeping the file open. When I exit the SBT I'm able to save the file. I've no idea why this is happening. Am I missing out with any settings?
I used MSI installer from SBT download page to install SBT. I tried using different editors but same problem persist. Is there a problem with SBT?